# How to reply linux prompt (based on keywords in prompt)

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, prompt

```
rm -i test_file*
rm: remove regular empty file 'test_file'?
rm: remove regular file 'test_file1'?
```

I want to reply "yes" in key word **empty** present in prompt and  reply other in not.

I tried  (it's not working)

```
yes | grep "empty" | rm -i test_file*
```

Comment: Which shell are you using `bash`? Searching from command outputs is not the efficient of ways, Can you use `find`? if you purpose is to delete all zero byte files?

Comment: @Inian is right, `find . -name "test_file*" -type f -empty -delete` does the trick

Answer (score 1):

When you are typing:

```
yes | grep "empty" | rm -i test_file*
```

You are passing `yes` result to `grep` which has no idea it should pass `yes` result to `rm`

YOu can do it this way (on bash) on a single file:

```
file test_file |grep empty && yes | rm -i test_file
```

On multiple files (still bash):

```
for file in *.dat; do file $file | grep empty && yes | rm -v $file ; done
```

Comment: It involves two calls for deleting single file !!

Comment: Well, the `find`-based solution in OP is still working then ;)

Comment: Yah, But i am looking for reply prompts logic  :)

Comment: In that case you should focus on return values instead of text, and also my second code snippet does it afaik. The `&&` is a _logical and_ operator.